# Why is the Facebook login on iOS not asking for correct permissions?

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I am using the Facebook login and I've tried different settings but **it always ends up by asking for the public profile and friends list permission**.

I manage to set additional permissions such as birthday, email and location, but totally fail to remove "Friends list".

How can I achieve that ?

I am using :

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;
```

and

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.loginView.readPermissions = [Utils getFacebookPermissions];

    ...
}
```

I get either this with `@[@"basic_info", @"email", @"user_birthday", @"user_location"];`
[image]

or this with `@[@"email"];`
[image]

Comment: I had a same problem and found that was using the wrong version of SDK.

Comment: That's all ? Just need to upgrade the SDK ?